# Reprogramming a Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I have been recently been collecting parts from various machines that I'm quite sure have micro-controllers. My question is this: is it possible to take the micro-controller and reprogram it (to be somewhat similar to an arduino, and at least Arduino IDE compatible) with only some to very little hassle? Would I need to remove it from its current circuit board and rebuild around the specific micro-controller? How feasible is all this?

Note: I know this is very vague, and was hoping only to get a very generalized answer.

Comment: Probably, the method depends on the part.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but depending upon the device could require a considerable amount of effort.  Given that microcontrollers are now commodity parts that can be had for a few dollars, the question could be asked "Why do you want to?" Unless the device uses a particularly exotic part that's of some academic interest, or you want to actually reverse engineer the device itself or modify its functionality somehow, the process will probably involve more than "very little" hassle and not be particularly enlightening.

Comment: @user24527 Also note that often the microcontrollers used in consumer devices that are cranked out in large volumes have their program memories configured at the chip factory, and are not reprogrammable.

Comment: Thank you for that note, I would not have known that otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arduino Uno is an Atmega328p AVR microcontroller in DIP package. If you can find one of those in a piece of equipment, then using it as an Arduino is as easy as hooking it up to the right ICSP header and using a in-circuit programmer.

I'd put the chances of finding a DIP AVR microcontroller in a random piece of gear at around 0.001% or so. Buying the $2.50 part from Digi-Key seems like a better way of going about finding one of those. Also, if the kind of microcontroller is any other kind (8051, PIC, ARM, 403, etc) then Arduino compatibility isn't going to happen.

Most if not all electronics made commercially in the last 10 years or more uses mostly surface mount technology. This not only makes large-scale assembly easier and cheaper, but it also saves on size and materials, which leads to lower cost. Surface mount chips are notoriously hard to de-solder and re-use for anything, requiring at a minimum a good workstation setup with hot air rework capability and good flux and de-solder braid, as well as some new carrier board to mount the device on, as it won't plug into a breadboard like a DIP part will.

Comment: Okay, This is very informative and helpful, thank you for the response

Comment: What about the bootloader?

Comment: You can program a serial bootloader into an AVR chip by using the USB in-circuit serial programmer, using the same 6-pin header. Commercial systems typically do not use serial boot loaders like that at all; that's an invention by the Arduino people to make the Arduino easier to interface with PCs.